# Hibernate Spring repository inheritance add more details to an Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, inheritance

I'm using hibernate and spring repository. I have 2 classes Person and PersonDetails which contains more details about the person.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    //name,birthdate ...

}
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_details")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class PersonDetails extends Person{
// private details accessible only for authorized user
}
```

When I create a Person I can't associate a PersonDetails it creates automatically a new instance of PersonDetails and add a new line in Person table.
Here's my repositories.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface PersonBaseRepository<T extends Person> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
T findByNameAndFirstname(String name,String firstname);
}
@Transactional
public interface PersonRepository extends PersonBaseRepository<Person> {
}
@Transactional
public interface PersonDetailsRepository extends PersonBaseRepository<PersonDetails > {
}
```

To solve this I could instanciate my Entities only with PersonDetails but in some cases PersonDetails fields will be empty.

When I call  findByNameAndFirstname from PersonDetailsRepository  and the person isn't in person_details table but only in person I want to return the person matches in PersonDetails object.

Does anyone have a workable solution ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use @Autowired PersonDetails to associate PersonDetails to Person class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't know how I could use @Autowired to link PersonDetail. Would you please explain how ? (I only use Autowired to inject repositories and servicies)

Comment: What do you want to do? Mapping or just link these two classes person and persondetails?

Comment: I would rather mapping to keep my hibernate inheritance.

Comment: [link]https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/how-to-define-association-mappings-between-hibernate-entities/  Refer this link may be this is what you are asking for.